# Failed to resolve: com.android.support

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the `Failed to resolve: com.android.support` when I build a new Android Studio project for the first time. I know there are several similar questions about this here on SO, but none of those solutions seem to work for me.

Not sure if this is relevant but note that the error is just `Failed to resolve: com.android.support` and not `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:...` or some other android support library package.

here is what I think are the relevant bits of code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "checkin.yetanotherdev.com.checkin"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-list_item:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

The Top-level build file (Android studio version > 3)

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.61'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

SDK tools screenshot
 [image: SDK tools screenshot]
Let me know if I provide any more info.